# Use the title= HTML attribute with RMarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, blogdown, abbr

I am trying to understand if it is possible to insert the HTML `title=` attribute (not necessarily inside an `<abbr>` tag) within an RMarkdown document (e.g. a blog post written through `blogdown`)

From W3C: the title attribute specifies extra information about an element. The information is most often shown as a tooltip text when the mouse moves over the element.

```
The <abbr title="World Health Organization">WHO</abbr> was founded in 1948.
```

Couldn't find anything regarding using in in RMarkdown tho

Comment: If your main idea is to get more information when hoovering over the text, you can use [tippy](https://tippy.john-coene.com/)

Comment: well yes and no, my idea was to find a way to use this specific HTML attribute in RMarkdown. I didn't know tippy, but loading an entire package just for this seems an overkill. Thanks for the suggestion tho, I might use it in my next Shiny app

Answer (score 2):

You can write raw HTML in Markdown. However, if you are using Hugo >= v0.60.0, [raw HTML will be ignored by default](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/raw-html-getting-omitted-in-0-60-0/22032). You need to set an option in your config file to enable it:

```
[markup.goldmark.renderer]
unsafe= true
```